# System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null

Tags: apex, unit-test, exception, failing-tests, null-pointer

Im getting the error 'System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null' when I run my test class, in the below test method.

```
 /*
  *  update a existing report
  */
  static testMethod void test_updateExistingReport(){
    if (!setupComplete){
      setupTestData();
    }
    Report__c rsReport = [SELECT Id, Name, Date_Filter__c, Report_Settings__c, EndDate__c, StartDate__c FROM Report__c WHERE Id=:report.Id LIMIT 1];


    System.Test.setCurrentPage(new PageReference('/apex/x?sel-parent-grc__risk__c=grc__Business_Unit__c,grc__Category__c&sel-risk__risk_assessment__c=Risk__Risk_Assessment_Date__c,Risk__Inherent_Rating__c,Risk__Residual_Rating__c&selectedBusinessUnitId='+newBusinessUnit.Id));
    CreateReportController cls = new CreateReportController(new ApexPages.standardController(rsReport));

    for (ReportHelper.RelatedList rList : cls.relatedList){ //ERROR
      if (rList.objectName.toLowerCase() == 'risk__risk_assessment__c'){
        rList.isSelected = true;
      }
    }

    cls.reportFilters[0].selectedField = 'grc__category__c';
    cls.reportFilters[0].selectedOperator = 'equals';
    cls.reportFilters[0].obj.put('grc__category__c','Operational'); 
    cls.reportFilters[0].isCustomField = true;
    cls.reportFilters[0].isLookorPickOrDate = true;
    cls.reportFilters[0].isDependentOrMultiPick = false;
    cls.selectedDateFilterField = 'grc__last_review_date__c';
    cls.saveReport();

    Report__c newReport = [SELECT Id, Name, Date_Filter__c, Report_Settings__c, EndDate__c, StartDate__c FROM Report__c WHERE Id=:report.Id LIMIT 1];
    System.assertEquals('grc__last_review_date__c',newReport.Date_Filter__c);
    System.assertEquals(System.today().addDays(-15), newReport.StartDate__c);
    System.assert(newReport.Report_Settings__c != null);
  }
```

Error shows up in the for loop in the above test method (Marked as '//ERROR' at the end of the line)

I wonder my method in the class should be changed. Below is my method in the class.

```
 public PageReference validateFilters(){
        // check the columns
        // Parent Object

        parentObj = ReportHelper.UpdateFields(parentObj, String.escapeSingleQuotes(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sel-parent-grc__risk__c')), parentObj.objName);

        // Related List
        for (ReportHelper.RelatedList rList : relatedList){
            if (rList.isSelected){
                rList.fieldsList = ReportHelper.UpdateFields(rList.fieldsList, String.escapeSingleQuotes(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sel-'+rList.objectName.toLowerCase())), rList.objectName);
            }
        }
        if (objName == parentObj.objName){ 
            updateFitler(reportFilters.get(filterNo-1));
        }else{
            for (ReportHelper.RelatedList rList : relatedList){
                if (objName == rList.objectName){
                    updateFitler(rList.relatedListFilters.get(filterNo-1));
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

How can I fix this exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be in the constructor for `CreateReportController`. Is isn't assigning a value to `relatedList`. So when you call

```
for (ReportHelper.RelatedList rList : cls.relatedList){ //ERROR
}
```

you are trying to iterate over null.

Check the constructor to ensure the relatedList is initialized.

Consider adding an assertion before the for loop to ensure the value is valid.

```
System.assertNotEquals(null, cls.relatedList, 'CreateReportController relatedList required');
```

If the Error line isn't the `For` loop then it might be the `rList.objectName` being null and then calling `.toLowerCase()` on it.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion.Related list is already initialized. I tried the assertion and it doesn't fail. I tried adding a null check,  to both scenarios (Related list and the object name) but still it fails.

Comment: @Butterfly Can you check exactly which line is throwing the NullPointerException? What do the RelatedList `objectName` and `isSelected` properties do? I.e. do they have a implementation that could cause a null reference.

Answer (score -1):

The problem will be in the constructor for CreateReportController. Is isn't assigning a value to relatedList. So when you call

for (ReportHelper.RelatedList rList : cls.relatedList){ //ERROR
}
you are trying to iterate over null.

Check the constructor to ensure the relatedList is initialized.

Consider adding an assertion before the for loop to ensure the value is valid.