# Test class error: System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null

Tags: unit-test, opportunity

Please help me on fixing this error in my test class

```java
@isTest
private class ItemizedReceiptTest {
    static testMethod void testMethodPostive(){
        Product2 prod = new Product2(
            Name = 'Test',
            IsActive = true
        );

        insert prod;

        Account acc = new Account(Name ='Test');
        insert acc;


        //Create your product
        Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity();
        testOpp.Name='Test Opportunity' ;
        testOpp.AccountId=acc.id;
        testOpp.StageName='Order Placed';
        testOpp.CloseDate= Date.newInstance(2019,03,28);
        insert testOpp;

        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();


        //Create your pricebook entry
        PricebookEntry pbEntry = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = pricebookId,
            Product2Id = prod.Id,
            UnitPrice = 100.00,
            IsActive = true

        );
        insert pbEntry;
        //create your opportunity line item.  This assumes you already have an opportunity created, called opp
        OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
            OpportunityId = testOpp.Id,
            Quantity = 5,
            PricebookEntryId = pbEntry.Id,
            TotalPrice = pbEntry.UnitPrice
        );
        insert oli;

        PageReference pageRef = Page.ItemizedReceipt;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        system.debug('Products'+prod);
        system.debug('acc'+acc);
        system.debug('testOpp'+testOpp);
        system.debug('pbEntry'+pbEntry);
        system.debug('oli'+oli);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(testOpp);
        ItemizedReceipt obj = new ItemizedReceipt(sc);//getting error
        obj.total();
    }
}
```

class:

```java
public with sharing class ItemizedReceipt {
    public List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLst          { set; get; } //List of Products in a Opportunity
    public Double                    totalPrice_cal  { set; get; } //Variable to calculate Total Price of all the products
    public Double                    totalGST_cal    { set; get; } //Variable to calculate GST of all the products
    public Double                    totalPST_cal    { set; get; } //Variable to calculate PST of all the products
    public Double                    totalAmt_cal    { set; get; } //Variable to calculate Total Amount of all the products
    public DateTime                  getCloseDate    { set; get; } //Variable to get the Created Date
    public String                    dayOfWeek       { set; get; } //Variable to store the Day from the Created Date
    public String                    accName         { set; get; } //Variable to store the Customer Name
    public  ItemizedReceipt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        if ( controller.getId() != null ) {
            oppLst = [SELECT Product2.Name, Opportunity.Id, Opportunity.CloseDate, TotalPrice, GST__c, PST__c,
                             Total_w_Tax__c, Opportunity.Account.Name
                      FROM   OpportunityLineItem
                      WHERE  Opportunity.Id=:controller.getId()
                     ];
            getCloseDate = oppLst[0].Opportunity.CloseDate;
            dayOfWeek = getCloseDate.format('EEEE');
            accName = (string)oppLst[0].Opportunity.Account.Name;
            totalPrice_cal = 0.0;
            totalGST_cal = 0.0;
            totalPST_cal = 0.0;
            totalAmt_cal = 0.0;
            total();//getting error
        }
    }  
    //Method calculates all the totals
    public  void total() {
        for ( integer i = 0; i < oppLst.size(); i++ ) {
            totalPrice_cal += oppLst[i].TotalPrice;
            totalGST_cal   += oppLst[i].GST__c;//getting error
            totalPST_cal   += oppLst[i].PST__c;
            totalAmt_cal   += oppLst[i].Total_w_Tax__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Also the GST__c,PST__c values are workflow field updates

Total_w_Tax__c is a formula field

If I remove

```
 totalGST_cal   += oppLst[i].GST__c;
 totalPST_cal   += oppLst[i].PST__c;
```

the above two lines of code, test class running successfully

Comment: Could you say in what code line?

Comment: getting error in class----------for last three lines



    
totalGST_cal   += oppLst[i].GST__c;
 totalPST_cal   += oppLst[i].PST__c;
  totalAmt_cal   += oppLst[i].Total_w_Tax__c; 










  In test class :
getting error at-----

ItemizedReceipt obj = new ItemizedReceipt(sc);.

 Actually  GST__c,PST__c fields  are updated using Workflow

 Total_w_Tax__c is a formula field

Comment: are you sure? No makes sense for me this msg in these lines...

Comment: unable to attach images here..please images below

Comment: I flagged the answer to be deleted. But, the error message is 'System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null', There is not argument in the line 45... So, no makes sense for me. Also, check if the query that is populating the optLst is going well. Look for this question -> https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45382/system-nullpointerexception-argument-cannot-be-null

Comment: There's some key information that seems to be missing right now. I think that you'll need to include the details of your workflow rules and field updates for the `GST__c` and `PST__c` fields, as I'd bet that your issue is that these two fields are null (because your workflow isn't being run). Probably the easiest way to fix this, however, would be to make rollup summary fields on `Opportunity` to handle this work (instead of trying to do it in your controller/extension).

Comment: hi thank you for the reply  @Derek F .I added rollup fields for GST__c,PST__c .now my test class  is working .